# Good way to dereference boost::shared_ptr in swig interface

Tags: python, c++, boost, swig

Is there a good, automated way to allow me to pass `shared_ptr`'s into functions that expect references in a SWIG interface?

I have a library that provides functions like:

```
// Module message
typedef boost::shared_ptr< Item > ItemPtr;
class Message{
  public:
     ItemPtr getItem( int index) ...
     ...
};
```

And then another library that uses them:

```
// Module client
class Client{
  public:
    void processItem( const Item& item );
}
```

These are in separate modules.

Obviously, I want to do something like:

```
>>> item=message.getItem(4)
>>> client.processItem( item )
```

in python, 
but the types do not line up, the `item` is a `shared_ptr` while the function expects a reference.

So far my solution is to override the functions in the interface file

```
%extend client {
    void processItem( ItemPtr ptr){ 
        $self->processItem( *ptr);
    }
}
```

Is there an approach  where where I can avoid having to duplicate all of the interface functions that expect a reference, but where I'll have `shared_ptr`'s?

Comment: What is wrong with that %extend solution? It is what I would do too. It is concise and easy to understand.

Comment: It doesn't scale easily to 10's (or hundreds) of such functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return an `Item` instance from your `getItem(int index)` function. Ohterwise you'll have to overload the functions in order to receive both arguments types (`shared_ptr` and `Item` references)

Comment: I see -- override the getter function at the source rather than at all of the the client destination functions.